# Create Replica From Server fails validation

Tags: arcgis-server, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service, arcgis-10.3, replication

I'm working on a simple geoprocessing service for ArcGIS Server 10.3 that's meant to allow users to create a replica of a geodata service. When I pull the 'Create Replica from Server' tool into ModelBuilder, two parameters are included: Replica Name and ZZZMISSING. When I attempt to make the Replica Name a model parameter, it fails to show up, and I have no idea what ZZZMISSING means. Searching on Geonet and other sources returns nothing.

If I attempt to continue on with running the model, the tool fails validation. This happens when run as a pure python script as well. Error 000584

Does anyone have insight into ZZZMISSING? Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.